# Importing Text files in python with numpy using np.genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to import a text file using Numpy's `genfromtxt` function.

I am not able to do so as it says there are too many values to unpack.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\loges\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\test4.py", line 12, in <module>
filling_values={-1:0})
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
[Finished in 1.1s]
```

I tried to define the variables as well according to the examples that I found online but none seem to work for me.

Can anyone help me identify my error?

This is an example of my text file which is respectively the XYZ coord and temp at that point.

```
-7                        -9.000000000000002       -3                       622.0582425616101
-6.500000000000001        -9.000000000000002       -3                       622.1498719223513
-6                        -9.000000000000002       -3                       622.2415012830924
```

This is my code. I would like to find the highest and mean temperature values. This is just the first 3 lines though. Its a file with alot of lines of data.

```
import numpy as np 

x, y, z, t = np.genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\loges\\OneDrive\\Documents\\School\\ME4101A FYP\\temperature600.txt',
             skip_header=0, skip_footer=0,
             unpack = True,
             names= ['x', 'y', 'z', 't'],
             dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float), ('t', float)],  
             usecols = (-1), 
             missing_values={-1:""},
             filling_values={-1:0})

print("Max Temp :", t.max())
```

Comment: For a start don't use unpacking with `genfromtxt`.  Use `data = genfromtxt(...)`. and make sure you understand the resulting array (shape and dtypes). If you get the `names` and `dtype` right, `data` should be a structured array, whose fields can be accessed by name, e.g. `data['x']`.

Answer (score 0):

Here `np.genfromtxt` return 3 values not 4 so that's your first problem. Second, if you are trying to get the max temperature why are you assigning individual variables (x,y,z,t) to the return value? This is what I would do:

```
import numpy as np 

temps = np.genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\loges\\OneDrive\\Documents\\School\\ME4101A FYP\\temperature600.txt',
             skip_header=0, skip_footer=0,
             unpack = True,
             names= ['x', 'y', 'z', 't'],
             dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float), ('t', float)],  
             usecols = (-1), 
             missing_values={-1:""},
             filling_values={-1:0})

data #=> array([(622.0582425616101,), (622.1498719223513,), (622.2415012830924,)], dtype=[('t', '<f8')])

print("Max Temp :", temps.max())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [91]: txt=b"""-7                        -9.000000000000002       -3          
    ...:              622.0582425616101
    ...: -6.500000000000001        -9.000000000000002       -3                  
    ...:      622.1498719223513
    ...: -6                        -9.000000000000002       -3                  
    ...:      622.2415012830924"""
```

With your `dtype` there's no need to unpack.  Just use the resulting structured array:

```
In [88]: dt=np.dtype([('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float), ('t', float)])
In [92]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=dt)
In [93]: data
Out[93]: 
array([(-7. , -9., -3.,  622.05824256), 
       (-6.5, -9., -3.,  622.14987192),
       (-6. , -9., -3.,  622.24150128)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8'), ('t', '<f8')])
In [94]: data['x']
Out[94]: array([-7. , -6.5, -6. ])
In [95]: data['t']
Out[95]: array([ 622.05824256,  622.14987192,  622.24150128])
In [96]: _.max()
Out[96]: 622.24150128309236
```

---

Your `genfromtxt` with `usecols` only creates one array, not 4:

```
In [97]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),skip_header=0, skip_footer=0,
    ...:              unpack = True,
    ...:              names= ['x', 'y', 'z', 't'],
    ...:              dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float), ('t', f
    ...: loat)],  
    ...:              usecols = (-1), 
    ...:              missing_values={-1:""},
    ...:              filling_values={-1:0})
    ...:              
Out[97]: 
array([( 622.05824256,), ( 622.14987192,), ( 622.24150128,)],
      dtype=[('t', '<f8')])
```